# Unable to connect via SSH to linux server with PPK authentication from windows system via Gitbash

Tags: linux, ssh, git-bash

I am not sure if this question is supposed to be asked here.

The instructions/steps to connect to this server have not been clear from the team which gives these.

I have got a key file named "client_key" which is apparently a PEM file. I am not sure if that is a PEM file though. I don't know how to verify it.

I kept it in my system at C:\Users\sandeepan\

I am trying to connect via SSH to a server like this -

```
$ ssh -i client_key root@<IP> -p 2222
ssh: connect to host <IP> port 2222: Connection timed out
```

I have been given the network level access it seems. Can someone point out if I am doing anything wrong in running the ssh command? Or do I need to use some other format of the given key?

**Update**

```
$ ssh -i client_key root@<IP> -p 2222 -vv
OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "<IP>" port 2222
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <IP> [<IP>] port 2222.
debug1: connect to address <IP> port 2222: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host <IP> port 2222: Connection timed out
```

Comment: To check if a file is PEM file use `file <filename>` ( o/p will be like `PEM RSA private key`). Are you sure ssh server is listening on port `2222` at `<IP>` and `root` user is accessible via `ssh`? Provide the o/p of `ssh -i client_key root@<IP> -p 2222 -vv`

Comment: Yes verified PEM file. Thanks. Added update with output of `-vv`. Please check.

Comment: _ Are you sure ssh server is listening on port 2222 at <IP> and root user is accessible via ssh?_

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that the `ssh` server you are trying to connect is listening on port `2222`. If yes, then review your firewall rules.

Second, `root` user access over `ssh` is usually disabled.